# How can I fix my Strategy Pattern C# program?

Tags: c#

My program is that the user can input any string and choose between two option the bubble sort or the quicksort and after that my program will execute the sorting but I am having a problem with the user input.

I don't know how to call the user input into my BubbleSort and also into my Quicksort.

I have red lines in my code specially on Implementaion and userInput. How will I fix it? I am a newbie in creating a strategy pattern.

Here are my errors:

```
/Users/xhantan/Projects/SortString/SortString/Program.cs(69,29,69,38): error CS0103: The name 'userInput' does not exist in the current context
/Users/xhantan/Projects/SortString/SortString/Program.cs(70,37,70,46): error CS0103: The name 'userInput' does not exist in the current context
/Users/xhantan/Projects/SortString/SortString/Program.cs(67,23,67,36): error CS0161: 'QuickSort.Implementaion(object)': not all code paths return a value
/Users/xhantan/Projects/SortString/SortString/Program.cs(42,30,42,39): error CS0103: The name 'userInput' does not exist in the current context
/Users/xhantan/Projects/SortString/SortString/Program.cs(39,23,39,37): error CS0161: 'BubbleSort.Implementation(object)': not all code paths return a value
/Users/xhantan/Projects/SortString/SortString/Program.cs(28,40,28,54): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'data' of 'IStrategy.Implementation(object)'
    0 Warning(s)
    6 Error(s)
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace SortStrategyPattern
{
    class Context
    {
        private IStrategy _strategy;

        public Context()
        { }

        public Context(IStrategy strategy)
        {
            this._strategy = strategy;
        }

        public void SetStrategy(IStrategy strategy)
        {
            this._strategy = strategy;
        }

        public void UserInput()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a string: ");

            String userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            userInput = this._strategy.Implementation();
        }
    }

    public interface IStrategy
    {
        object Implementation(object data);
    }

    class BubbleSort : IStrategy
    {
        public object Implementation(object data)
        {
            char temp;
            char[] charStr = userInput.ToCharArray();
            for (int x = 1; x < charStr.Length; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < charStr.Length - 1; y++)
                {
                    if (charStr[y] > charStr[y + 1])
                    {
                        temp = charStr[y];
                        charStr[y] = charStr[y + 1];
                        charStr[y + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }


            Console.Write("Bubble Sort: ");
            foreach (char input in charStr)
            {
                Console.Write(input + ", ");
            }
        }
    }

    class QuickSort : IStrategy
    {
        public object Implementaion(object data)
        {
            var charArray = userInput.ToCharArray();
            quicksort(charArray, 0, userInput.Length);

            Console.Write("Quick Sort: ");
            foreach (char s in charArray)
            {
                Console.Write(s + ", ");
            }
        }

        static void quicksort(char[] userInput, int start, int end)
        {
            if (start < end)
            {
                int pivotIndex = partition(userInput, start, end);
                quicksort(userInput, start, pivotIndex);
                quicksort(userInput, pivotIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

        static void swap(char[] userInput, int i, int j)
        {
            char temp = userInput[i];
            userInput[i] = userInput[j];
            userInput[j] = temp;
        }

        static int partition(char[] userInput, int start, int end)
        {
            int pivotIndex = userInput[start];
            int swapIndex = start;
            for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
            {
                if (userInput[i] < pivotIndex)
                {
                    swapIndex++;
                    swap(userInput, i, swapIndex);
                }
            }
            swap(userInput, start, swapIndex);
            return swapIndex;
        }

        public object Implementation(object data)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char response;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Choose between the two sorting strategies:");
                Console.WriteLine("\ta) - Bubble Sort");
                Console.WriteLine("\tb) - Quick Sort");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Your option: ");

                {
                    response = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                switch (response.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    case "a":

                        new BubbleSort();
                        break;


                    case "b":

                        new QuickSort();
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer. Please enter a valid option.");
                        response = '\0';
                        break;
                }

            } while (response == '\0');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first step in fixing compiler errors ("redlines", "squiggly lines" etc) is to *read the error message(s)* - the compiler is not hiding anything from you.  Then, after you have t*thoroughly* researched the issue(s), if you need help be sure to tell us in your post what those errors are so we know what problem we are solving.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp sorry i already edited my question with errors

Comment: The compiler shows you what errors you have. Everything what you need to do is probably learn some basics of C#.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there. However, let's improve it a little:

**Interface**

```
public interface ISort
{
   T[] Sort<T>(T[] data) where T : IComparable;
}
```

**BubbleSort**

```
public class BubbleSort : ISort
{
   public T[] Sort<T>(T[] data) where T : IComparable
   {
      var result = data.ToArray();
      for (var x = 1; x < result.Length; x++)
      {
         for (var y = 0; y < result.Length - 1; y++)
         {
            if (result[y].CompareTo(result[y + 1]) <= 0) continue;
            var temp = result[y];
            result[y] = result[y + 1];
            result[y + 1] = temp;
         }
      }

      return result;
   }
}
```

**QuickSort**

```
public class QuickSort : ISort
{
   public T[] Sort<T>(T[] data) where T : IComparable
   {
      var result = data.ToArray();
      InternalQuickSort(result, 0, result.Length);
      return result;

   }

   private static void InternalQuickSort<T>(T[] data, int start, int end) where T : IComparable
   {
      if (start >= end) return;
      var pivotIndex = Partition(data, start, end);
      InternalQuickSort(data, start, pivotIndex);
      InternalQuickSort(data, pivotIndex + 1, end);
   }

   private static void Swap<T>(T[] data, int i, int j) where T : IComparable
   {
      T temp = data[i];
      data[i] = data[j];
      data[j] = temp;
   }

   private static int Partition<T>(T[] data, int start, int end) where T : IComparable
   {
      var pivotIndex = data[start];
      var swapIndex = start;
      for (var i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
      {
         if (data[i].CompareTo(pivotIndex) >= 0) continue;
         swapIndex++;
         Swap(data, i, swapIndex);
      }

      Swap(data, start, swapIndex);
      return swapIndex;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private static ISort GetSorter(char option)
   => char.ToLower(option) switch
   {
      'a' => new BubbleSort(),
      'b' => new QuickSort(),
      _ => null
   };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   char response;

   do
   {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Choose between the two sorting strategies:");
      Console.WriteLine("\ta) - Bubble Sort");
      Console.WriteLine("\tb) - Quick Sort");
      Console.WriteLine("\tx) - To Quit");
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.Write("Your option: ");

      if (!char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out response))
         continue;

      if (response == 'x')
         break;

      var sorter = GetSorter(response);

      if (sorter == null)
         continue;

      Console.Write("Type something to sort: ");

      var data = Console.ReadLine();

      Console.WriteLine();

      var result = sorter.Sort(data.ToCharArray());

      Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));

   } while (response != 'x');
}
```

**Output**

```
Choose between the two sorting strategies:
        a) - Bubble Sort
        b) - Quick Sort
        x) - To Quit

Your option: a
Type something to sort: qwertyuiop

e, i, o, p, q, r, t, u, w, y

Choose between the two sorting strategies:
        a) - Bubble Sort
        b) - Quick Sort
        x) - To Quit

Your option: b
Type something to sort: qwertyuiop

e, i, o, p, q, r, t, u, w, y

Choose between the two sorting strategies:
        a) - Bubble Sort
        b) - Quick Sort
        x) - To Quit

Your option: x
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

> Generics introduce the concept of type parameters to .NET, which make
> it possible to design classes and methods that defer the specification
> of one or more types until the class or method is declared and
> instantiated by client code. For example, by using a generic type
> parameter T, you can write a single class that other client code can
> use without incurring the cost or risk of runtime casts or boxing
> operations

[IComparable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-5.0)

> Defines a generalized type-specific comparison method that a value
> type or class implements to order or sort its instances.